# What does the getResponseMessage() method of HttpURLConnection return?

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I am writing an android application which uses [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for downloads.  I am wondering what the [getResponseMessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseMessage()) method returns.  If I make a successful (200 OK) request, will it return the same thing as the data given by [getInputStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()) ? What will it return if my request receives a non-200 status code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will return an HTTP response message. Have a look here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
Like the famous `404 Not Found`.

The docs clearly say:
`Returns the response message returned by the remote HTTP`

It doesn't return the data you want to retrieve. It gives you information about your connection.

Comment: Awesome.  This is what I thought but I wanted to make sure.  So in this example getResponseCode() would return the integer 404 and getResponseMessage() would return "404 Not Found"?  Answer accepted, thank you!